# uso de variables en comparaciones jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo dos divs uno con el data-coc ="2" y otro con data-coc = "1" mi problema es que si utilizo una variable para ocultar los divs se me ocultan ambos, en cambio si uso un valor funciona correctamente

**Usando variable**

```
var testing = "1";
$('.bookitem').not('[data-coc ~= testing]').hide();
```

**Usando valor**

```
$('.bookitem').not('[data-coc ~= "1"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar una variable tendrías que concatenarla o usar [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) te dejo los dos casos, en ambos funciona igual, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
var testing = "1";
$('.bookitem').not(`[data-coc ~= ${testing}]`).hide();

//$('.bookitem').not('[data-coc ~= '+testing+']').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-coc="1" class="bookitem"> div1</div>
<div data-coc="2" class="bookitem"> div2</div>
```